# Efficient Django query for model with foreign key to itself

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-optimization

I'm building a simple blog post website using Django. Basically there are two models: Post and Comment, where the comment model looks like this:

```
class Comment:
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    # A comment can have many replies, and an user can only reply to the "parent" comment (A comment which isn't a reply to any comment)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, 'like_comments', blank=True)
    # Some other fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.reply is not None:
            self.post = self.reply.post
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a class-based view which inherits Django generic `DetailView` to retrieve a specific post. The problem is I also want to retrieve all comments of the post, along with the replies of those comments and number of likes **in an efficient way**. What would be the most performant way to do so?

I came up with the following way:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

# Some views here ...

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'core/post_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return Post.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('comments', queryset=Comment.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('likes'))))
```

However, when I inspect the query using QuerySet.query, the raw SQL looks the same as if I used "Post.objects.all()". I'm not sure if I'm doing wrong or I misunderstood something. If I'm wrong, how do I fix it? Otherwise, is this efficient yet?

Here's the part of the template which used to display the comments (I haven't written for the replies display yet, but I'm also planning to write a for loop and display similar to the parent comment):

```html
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="flex">
        <!-- Some html for avatar display truncated -->
        <div class="w-full pl-2 mb-2 shadow-md rounded-md">
            <article class="px-1 pb-1">
                <header class="flex items-center px-4 justify-between">
                    <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center">
                        <p class="font-semibold">{{ comment.author.username }}</p>
                        <p>|</p>
                        <time class="text-sm" datetime="{{ comment.created_at }}">
                            {% if comment.created_this_year %}
                                {{ comment.created_at|date:"M j" }}
                            {% else %}
                                {{ comment.created_at|date:"M j Y" }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </time>
                        {% if comment.created_at != comment.updated_at %}
                            <p>|</p>
                            <p class="text-sm">
                                Edited on
                                <time datetime="{{ comment.updated_at }}">
                                    {% if comment.created_this_year %}
                                        {{ comment.created_at|date:"M j" }}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{ comment.created_at|date:"M j Y" }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </time>
                            </p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <details class="dropdown dropdown-end">
                        <summary class="btn">...</summary>
                        <ul class="p-4 shadow menu dropdown-content z-[1] bg-base-100 rounded-box w-72">
                            <li><a>Copy link</a></li>
                            <li><a>Report</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </details>
                </header>
                <div class="p-4 prose">
                    {{ comment.markdown_content|safe }}
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share how you render this in the template? Not with all the styling, etc. but just loops, etc. that you use.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I added it, only highlight the part which render the comments

Comment: What if you work with `Post.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('comments', queryset=Comment.objects.select_related('author').annotate(num_likes=Count('likes'))))`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Oh I tried. I wasn't wrong. It did only hit the database twice. I think I have a misunderstood with the query method of QuerySet.  I read the docs back and turns out I could have use connection.queries from django.db to track all the queries ran. Still I wonder if this is the most performant way to do it?

Comment: @The2nd In case you missed it in the docs, the second database hit is because of how `prefetch_related()` works. I can think of two alternatives that may or may not perform better, but they're way less straightforward than the `prefetch_related()` syntax suggested by willem.

Comment: @Supra621 I think I will go ahead with the ```prefetch_related``` syntax way (I also modified to get the replies). Yet I curious on why the ```.query``` properties of the QuerySet doesn't seem to show the actual sql query that Django will execute as what it shows with the above query just looks identical to ```Post.objects.all()```. What I found so far about this property in the docs is:  _The query attribute is an opaque object. It represents the internals of the query construction and is not part of the public API._ May be because it's _not part of the public API_?

Comment: @The2nd "not part of the public API" means that it's not intended for you to modify directly. The output from `.query` look the same because the "main" query doesn't have to change - prefetch queries are a totally separate SQL statement. Django records the prefetch instructions on another property, though I don't recall exactly where.